# GetEnumerator problem in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

i got this GetEnumerator problem.. here's my situation

```
        Panel eachPanel = new Panel();
        eachPanel.Size = new Size(pnlProcessCon.Width - 27, 24);
        eachPanel.Location = new Point(5, startPoint);
        eachPanel.BackColor = (defaultColor == alterColor[0]) ? alterColor[1] : alterColor[0];            

        TextBox txtProcess = new TextBox();
        txtProcess.Size = new Size(50, 20);
        txtProcess.Location = new Point(2,2);
        txtProcess.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        txtProcess.Text = "P" + Convert.ToString(startProcess);

        TextBox txtBurstTime = new TextBox();
        txtBurstTime.Size = new Size(50, 20);
        txtBurstTime.Location = new Point(txtProcess.Right + 70, 2);
        txtBurstTime.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;

        TextBox txtPriority = new TextBox();
        txtPriority.Size = new Size(50, 20);
        txtPriority.Location = new Point(txtBurstTime.Right + 70, 2);
        txtPriority.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;

        eachPanel.Controls.Add(txtProcess);
        eachPanel.Controls.Add(txtBurstTime);
        eachPanel.Controls.Add(txtPriority);

        pnlProcessCon.Controls.Add(eachPanel);
```

but when i call each of their text and add to dictionary, i got this error..

```
Error   1   foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Panel' because 'System.Windows.Forms.Panel' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'    C:\Users\vrynxzent@yahoo.com\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Scheduler\Scheduler\Form1.cs 68  13  Scheduler
```

and got my error here..

```
foreach (var each in pnlProcessCon)
        {
            String[] temp = new String[3];
            foreach (var process in each)
            {
                temp = process.Text;                    
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few issues there.

First, you should enumerate the Controls collections. Second, you will have to cast each control to `TextBox` before you can retrieve the text. Third, you declared `temp` as an array, so you can't directly assign a string to it. Fourth (as Henk Holterman pointed out), you should use actual types and not `var` in the `foreach` loops.

I'm going to take a stab at working code here. Feel free to adjust for your own needs.

```
TextBox txtProcess = new TextBox();
txtProcess.Name = "Process";
//configure other textboxes, add to panels, etc.

foreach (Panel each in pnlProcessCon.Controls)
{
    String[] temp = new String[3];
    foreach (Control control in each.Controls)
    {
        if(control.Name == "Process")
        {
            temp[0] = ((TextBox)control).Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ay.. grrrrr.. i know this thing.. hehe.. sorry for asking stupid questions.. im just drunk.. thanks for the answer.. ;)

Comment: @vrynxzent, why are you programming drunk?!

Comment: I don't think `var` will work - Controls is an old style collection.

Comment: @svick even though I +1'd your comment, let me pose a counter question: "why aren't you programming drunk?!"

Comment: @Davy8, because I don't want to go like “OMG, what have I done? Quickly, how do I revert this code so that no one ever sees it again?” the next morning.

Comment: first time me drinking beer.. and i need to code a project.. :D

Answer (score 1):

This would be the general idea (note: no `var`)

```
foreach (Panel p in pnlProcessCon.Controls)
{
    foreach (Control process in p.Controls)
    {
    }                    
}
```

But make sure `pnlProcessCon` only contains Panels.